# no such file to load -- debugger rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

When i run rspec on a file .rb

It gives me `rb:2:in require: no such file to load -- debugger (LoadError)`

However when I type
`$irb`

```
require 'debugger'
```

returns

```
=> true
```

What is wrong with ruby or rvm?

Comment: More details might help us to understand the problem. Are you using rspec inside file?

Comment: I am in a directory that has a .rb file where the first line calls require 'debugger', but when I run rspec on the file in terminal i get the error: no such file to load -- debugger (LoadError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People helped me, turns out i did not install rspec gem file, i got it confused with rails-rspec